# I need assistance with printing something out within an array

Tags: java, arrays, int

I am attempting to locate a specific number within an array and then print out how many times it is IN the array.

```
public static int favorite(int[] digit, int fave)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <digit.length; x++)
    {
        if ( digit[x] == fave)
        {return x;}
    }
    return -1;
  }
```

Would something like that work? And What would I do to print it out? favorite(int[]digit, fave); doesn't seem to make sense to me.

Comment: what you are turning is the index in your array where you found fav ... as Immer said, you need a counter that returns at the end of your loop

Comment: *"Would something like that work?"* Well, did something like that work when you tried it? *"favorite(int[]digit, fave); doesn't seem to make sense to me."* You may also want to have a look some of the [official Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/), they are concise and well-written.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count the number of occurance of specific element in array/list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812543/how-to-count-the-number-of-occurance-of-specific-element-in-array-list) among numerous others written by people who will ultimately be upset they can't get a job because they copied and pasted their way through school.

Answer (score 2):

whenever you deal with *"how many times"* then you should have a *counter* . You may try:

```
public static int favorite(int[] digit, int fave)
{   
    int count=0;
    for (int x = 0; x <digit.length; x++)
    {
        if ( digit[x] == fave)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
  }
```

To print it out:

```
System.out.println("Number of occurrence:"+ favorite(digit, fave));
```

assuming that you have something like `int[] digit = {1,2,3,2,4,2,5};` and `int fave = 2;`

Comment: Splendid! However, how do i then print it out? The count that and digit in main that is.

Comment: That was all? Thank you very much. I know comprehend my issue.